# Odoo 12. Missing required value for the field 'Object' (model_id) when I change the permission file ir.model.access.csv and upgrade the module

Tags: module, permissions, upgrade, odoo-12

I have created my own module in odoo 12. And I have change the permission file- ir.model.access.csv. All the code is as below.

ir.model.access.csv :

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_student_student,access.student.student,model_student_student,,1,1,1,0
```

./models/models :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class StudentStudent(models.Model):
    _name = "student.student"
    _description = "description"
    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    age = fields.Integer(string="Age")
    photo = fields.Binary(string="Image")
    gender = fields.Selection(
        [("male", "Male"), ("female", "Female"), ("others", "Others")], string="Gender"
    )
    student_dob = fields.Date(string="Date of Birth")
    student_blood_group = fields.Selection(
        [
            ("A+", "A+ve"),
            ("B+", "B+ve"),
            ("O+", "O+ve"),
            ("AB+", "AB+ve"),
            ("A-", "A-ve"),
            ("B-", "B-ve"),
            ("O-", "O-ve"),
            ("AB-", "AB-ve"),
        ],
        string="Blood Group",
    )
    nationality = fields.Many2one("res.country", string="Nationality")
```

error message occur when I try to upgrade my module :

```
Exception: Module loading assettracking failed: file assettracking\security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
 No matching record found for external id 'model_student_student' in field 'Object'
Missing required value for the field 'Object' (model_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your model is loaded into the database, if not restart your server before upgrading to load it. If you already did that try using: `module_name.model_student_student` in your CSV file.

Comment: I have restarted the server and database, and also uninstall and reinstall the module.I got this message[picture](https://imgur.com/091k8Bv) when I reinstall the module.

Comment: I am using odoo on window. I install the module on localhost browser.

Comment: Problem seem to be solved after restart the services-odoo-server-12.0. but my student_view still not exist in the module and I cannot access to module from the top left of application [picture](https://imgur.com/Gg5tUtb)../views/student_view.xml: [link](https://gist.github.com/sambatlim/a7fe7f3c78249b80de0c1c3b397f24af). _manifest_.py: [link](https://gist.github.com/sambatlim/dc27642200840b6aa7583eac179495d0)

Comment: Solution of the module not show on the top left menu: I forgot to define the action menu in my student_view.xml. updated file [/views/student_view.xml](https://gist.github.com/sambatlim/945a575d0b278f7ec4570c16eb60e6db)

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have written **init**.py file for student.student model.

If yes then please try below code in .csv file`access_student_student,access_student_student,model_student_student,,1,1,1,0`

Answer (score 0):

A trick i usually do is I add a model and then start the server process, the system will give me a warning that this model does not have permissions and gives u an example of the line to add to ir.model.access.csv. I copy that from the shell window and paste it into ir.model.access.csv and edit accordingly.

With Odoo 12 i have found that you need to specify a user group and in the ir.model.access.csv file. If i do not specify the user group, the menu item would not appear for my users.
I have set custom user groups with differing permissions, but the usual default is to specify permissions for base.erp_user & base.erp_manager. An example of the entries would be

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_student_student_user,access_student_student_user,model_student_student,base.group_user,1,1,1,0
access_student_student_admin,access_student_student_admin,model_student_student,base.group_erp_manager,1,1,1,1
```

With the above example, ordinary users will be able to create, read and edit a student record but they cannot delete records, while an administrator can delete records. If u specify custom users groups the menu option for Students will only appear if the logged on user is in those groups.

Comment: I got the solution. The solution is restart the server - for windows go to the task manager and find services then restart odoo-server-(your odoo version)  service.